# Use of uninitialized value \$price in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line

Tags: perl, initialization

SO I have this data set

```
The Lion King!
Tumbleweed Connection!Elton John!123.32
Photographs & Memories!Jim Croce!4.95
Heads & Tales!Harry Chapin!12.50
```

and this script which give me uninitialized errrors

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open( my $filehandle , "<", $ARGV[0]) || die $!;
my @lines = <$filehandle> ;
close($filehandle) ;

foreach (@lines) {
    chop;
    my ($album ,$artist,$price );
    ($album, $artist, $price) = (split(/!/));
    print ("Album=$album    Artist=$artist    Price=$price\n");
    }
```

Errors

```
 casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~/david_mendinets. $ ./11LIST02.pl FORMAT.DAT
 Use of uninitialized value $price in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line 13.
Album=The Lion King    Artist=    Price=
Album=Tumbleweed Connection    Artist=Elton John    Price=123.32
Album=Photographs & Memories    Artist=Jim Croce    Price=4.95
Album=Heads & Tales    Artist=Harry Chapin    Price=12.50
Use of uninitialized value $album in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line  13.
Use of uninitialized value $artist in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line 13.
Use of uninitialized value $price in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line 13.
Album=    Artist=    Price=
```

So i fixed the script - but i am still getting one error.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 use warnings;
  3 use strict;
  4
  5 open( my $filehandle , "<", $ARGV[0]) || die $!;
  6 my @lines = <$filehandle> ;
  7 close($filehandle) ;
  8
  9 foreach (@lines) {
 10     chop;
 11     my $album ="";
 12     my $artist ="";
 13     my  $price ="" ;
 14     ($album, $artist, $price) = (split(/!/));
 15     if (length $album) {
 16     print ("Album=$album    Artist=$artist    Price=$price\n");
 17     }
 18     elsif (length $price) {
 19     print ("Album=$album    Artist=$artist    Price=$price\n");
 20     }
 21 }



casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~/david_mendinets. $ ./11LIST02.pl FORMAT.DAT
Use of uninitialized value $price in concatenation (.) or string at ./11LIST02.pl line 16.
Album=The Lion King    Artist=    Price=
Album=Tumbleweed Connection    Artist=Elton John    Price=123.32
Album=Photographs & Memories    Artist=Jim Croce    Price=4.95
Album=Heads & Tales    Artist=Harry Chapin    Price=12.50
casper_mint@casper-mint-dell ~/david_mendinets. $
```

I am having trouble getting rid of that last error - i do onto understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to restructure your code from lines 11-14 like this:

```
my ($album, $artist, $price) = (split(/!/));
$album ||= "";
$artist ||= "";
$price ||= "" ;
```

Split the values into the variables, and then assign a default value ("") if any of the values is undefined. That should fix you right up.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the line which get splitted has fewer than three elements, so default values could be assigned,

```
$_ //= "" for 
  my ($album, $artist, $price) = split /!/;
```

`//=` assigns empty string only when mentioned variables are `undef`, and not when they generally evaluate to [`false`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=what%20is%20true%20and%20false%20in%20Perl?).